# Prevent downloading of pdf/jpg/ppt/docx/ical or any other file types while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping urls. And when some urls wont have any html data, rather it will download ppt, pdf or docx files (https://madisonsymphony.org/msol11-movie-music-slides/) . How can we prevent autodownloading of files from urls during scraping even if html data is present or not.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/home/ubuntu/selenium_drivers/chromedriver")

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument("--incognito")

url = "https://madisonsymphony.org/msol11-movie-music-slides/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = options)
driver.get(url)
html_content = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

Tried adding the following option to selenium chrome driver. But still it downloads to /dev/null

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": r"\dev\null",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

Also tried the following which results in no change

```
prefs = {
    "download_restrictions": 3,
}
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", prefs
)
```

Comment: Before attempting to download, you can try sending a `HEAD` request and check that the `Content-Type` header on the response matches `text/html`, but even that is not 100% guarantee.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Some urls will give html data along with autodownload. I am looking for a complete blocking of autodownload

Comment: I don't think it works like that. It either returns HTML or a binary content. You probably meant that an HTML response might have links that refer to downloadable content. Just make sure that whenever you are crawling into a new URL, you check the content type